# Flutter - Selecting a contact from list selects ALL contacts

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I have a list that shows phone contacts after getting permission. I have a kind of tag function to select a conctact.
What happens is that when I pick one, ALL contacts switch value to true.
I need just the one selected to change to true.
Here's the code so it may be more clear.

```
StatefulBuilder buildContactItem(Contact contact, double screenwidth, double screenheight) {
    return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
           
          return Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                dense: false,
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isSelected = !isSelected;
                    if (isSelected == false) {
                      listContactosSeleccionados.removeWhere((element) =>
                          element.displayName == contact.displayName);
                    } else {
                      listContactosSeleccionados.add(contact);
                    }
                  });
                },
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18),
            trailing: buildIconListTile(isSelected),
            leading: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              child: Container(
                height: screenheight*0.065,
                width: screenwidth*0.13,
                color: Color(0xffafb3af),
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(contact.initials(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "Raleway-SemiBold",
                          fontSize: 26,
                          color: Color(0xffe5e6e5),
                        ))),
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(contact.displayName ?? '',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "Raleway-Light",
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  color: Color(0xffb3b3b3),
                )),
          ),
          Divider()
        ],
      );
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be usefull if you could post the code related to the contacts loading and the selection handling.

Anyway, the problem is probably related to the way you are handling selection.
From the code I can see you are setting `isSelected` to true when one of the contact gets tapped.

I think you only declared one `isSelected` which is working for all of your contacts.

I would create an array of boolean called `isSelected` instead of a single boolean. The length of that array should be the same as the number of contacts.

I would then give each contact an index starting from 0.

Then I would change the `onTap` function to work like this:

```
isSelected[index] = !isSelected[index];
 if (isSelected[index] == false) {
 //Your code
}
```